# How to order Months in a categorical order in python, ie Jan, Feb, Mar etc...?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I'm creating a bar chart which has 'Months' on the x axis, however they are displayed in a random order, how do I order the months logically, ie Jan, Feb, Mar...

Here is my code...

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    sns.countplot(x=boeing_df.order_month);
    plt.title('Most Popular Order Month');ype here
```

TIA

Comment: Hi Rebecca and welcom to SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `order` parameter of [`countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) and give it your list of months. A convenience might be to use [`calendar.month_abbr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_abbr):

```
import calendar
sns.countplot(x=boeing_df.order_month, order=calendar.month_abbr[1:])
```